# How can i calculate density of every centroid in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, cluster-sample

i have kmeans clustered data, and cluster centroids of the kmeans. I want to calculate density of each cluster centroid and remove the cluster of the highest cluster centroid density. I did my research, and find this formula.

[image]

N(c) is a set of neighbor cluster centroids of cluster c and should be 5 I tried to implement the algorithm but couldn't do. Can you help me implement it?

Here is my code so far:

```
df = make_blobs(n_samples=5000, n_features=15,centers=15, cluster_std=1,random_state=10)
X,y=df
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=10)
TrainData=X_train,y_train
n_clusters_sampling=10

kmeans2 = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clusters_sampling,random_state=10)
kmeans2.fit(X_train)
centroids = kmeans2.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: Could you link where you're getting this definition?

Comment: Sounds like you are attempting to combine K-Means clustering with Kernel Density Estimation. The answer to what you are actually asking is to find the volume of the Vornoi cell associated with each centroid. Then divide number of points for each centroid with this volume to find centroid density. The vornoi cell's convex hull can diverge significantly from a spherical approximation of points in each cell, so you may think twice about your approach. Link to python code for computing volume of vornoi cell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634993/volume-of-voronoi-cell-python